# wow.js is not working. Even after I removed other js files and checked the path, I found no improvement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have no idea about why wow.js isn't working.

What I've checked so far

1. Checked the path and whether animate.css works.
2. deleted other js files to make sure the possibility that wow.js can't be used with other js files.

For some reasons, the head part was not displayed so let me paste the URL that I'm working on instead.
https://azzurro2017.github.io/

***The codes I wrote is for iphone6 so I would like you to check that URL with device mode. ***

There are 2 classes as below.

①class="wow fadeIn" for img tag 
②class="animated shake" for p tag

I confirmed that ① is not working as of now but ② works.

I'm looking forward to your advise.　
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: “doesn’t work” is not a problem description. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. Don’t post your code as pictures. Instead include it as formatted code in the question itself. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: Also, the dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested?

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
This is the first time to post so let me check how to ask questions properly.

As to the 2nd question, I'm afraid but I don't understand it.
Can you ask me that questions in another words ?

Comment: Have you opened the dev tools? Find the “Network” tab and try to find where `js/wow.min.js` is requested. If it’s not found, you’ll see a 404 response, otherwise a 200 response or a 3xx response.

Comment: 404 response was found, which means wow.js is not working properly ?
Even jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js is also not working.....

Comment: Yes. Now, you can see which _actual_ URL is requested and, if it doesn’t match your expectations, you can fix it in the code.

Comment: Let me try to post my complete codes here. 
Basically I didn't edit the free js sources that I found online.
That's why I couldn't help thinking that the path was the main cause of this problem.

Comment: 404 means the path *is* the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer ! 
Let me check that again.

Answer (score 0):

Re-confirm path and use `animate.min.css` with new download of `wow.min.js`.

-Other's seem fine.
This may help you!!

link for `animate.min.css` is available on `https://github.com/daneden/animate.css`
You can download it this link.

Comment: animate.min.js ?? Did you mean animate.min.css ?
I tired to find animate.min.js from the web site providing wow.js and animate.css but couldn't find it.

Comment: https://github.com/matthieua/WOW

https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. Thanks for your comment and let me try this one.